# Python: 'int' object not iterable in list of 2-tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Update**:

Sorry for the inconvenience, but for some reasons I assumed lists to be homogenuous ([removed some ranting]). Thanks for the time you invested nonetheless. And here is the TL;DR answer to my own question:

If python tells you, that the first element of a list is a tuple, don't rely on it. You might have made a mistake and the second element is not.

**Original post**:

Ok, there are a lot of questions having similar titles but in all of these it was quite obvious the OPs wanted to iterate over an integer (mostly using 'sum'). However in my case I'm a bit stumbled by the insanity I'm not used to using statically typed languages...

So here's the first snippet:

```
print type(delta_info.moving_leaves)
print type(delta_info.moving_leaves[0])
print len(delta_info.moving_leaves)
print len(delta_info.moving_leaves[0])

# transform moving points in leaves
for (l, t) in (delta_info.moving_leaves):
    for p in leaves[l].cluster.points:
        # transform p using t...
```

Output:

```
<type 'list'>
<type 'tuple'>
62
2
File "/home/slim/source/compression/patchbased/computeDelta.py", line 153, in main
    for (l, t) in (delta_info.moving_leaves):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

And here's the context for delta_info.moving_leaves (I know it's a rather complex context, but I figured you'd ask for it anyway):

```
delta_info.moving_leaves = moving_correspondences(damaged, max_distance, grid_size, fitness_threshold, points)
```

where moving_correspondences(...) ends in:

```
result = []
for leaf in leaves:
    icp_results = moving_icp_search(leaf, max_distance, grid_size, fitness_threshold, heuristics, corr, num_corr)
    if (len(icp_results)):
        result.append(icp_results[0])
        # ... no actions on result anymore
return result
```

And finally moving_icp_search:

```
# ...
results = map(lambda p: moving_icp_grid_point(leaf, start + step * p, corr, num_corr), grid)
results[:] = sorted(filter(lambda r: r[1] and r[0] < threshold, results))
if (len(results)):
    _, _, transformations = zip(*results)
    # ... no actions on transformations or leaf.id
    # leaf.id is an integer, transformations[0] a numpy ndarray
    return [(leaf.id, list(transformations)[0])]
return []
```

So I'll close with a concrete question:
Under which circumstances does python2 tell me that something is a list of 2-tuples and then refuse to iterate it due to considering it an integer?

Comment: What is `leaves[l].cluster.points`?

Comment: leaves = [ClusterTreeNode], ClusterTreeNode.cluster = [Cluster], Cluster.points = np.array((n,3), np.double)

Comment: Not *all* of your entries in `delta_info.moving_leaves` are tuples. *At least one* is a single `int` value.

Comment: Ok, I tried 'for i in deltainfo.moving_leaves: print type(i)' and it told me, that the first one is a tuple and the second one an int. Are lists not homogenous?

Comment: The correct way to check of which class is an object is with `isinstance(object, class)` Check with that

Comment: @Martijn: Care to c&p your comment as an answer?

Comment: @RichardVock: Lists can contain anything (including themselves!).

Comment: "the insanity of pythons type system continuously amazes me"
You're programming in a dynamically typed language and are confused by it being dyamic?

Comment: dynamic typing does not imply heterogenous list types. In fact in most languages I've seen (independent of the type system) lists are (mathematically) defined over the power of some fixed field. And I have to admit (aside from some experiments a few years ago) I'm working with python 2 days now, so most probably my ranting is unjustified ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception it is clear that *at least one entry* in your `delta_info.moving_leaves` sequence is *not* a two-value tuple, but an `int`.

Whatever produced that sequence, is not producing homogenous values.

I am having real trouble following through your sketchy function outlines; use some print statements to verify that you are understanding values produced properly.

Comment: List construction was indeed faulty due to some empty tuples. Your comment helped a lot, thank you.